# Does DMARC TXT record require trailing semicolon?

Tags: dns, dmarc

I've left off the trailing semicolon in each TXT record of my DMARC records, but I've never thought if this is ignoring some convention, or could cause lookups to fail somehow.

For example, is there any difference between:

```
"v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:dmarc@mydomain.com"
```

and

```
"v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:dmarc@mydomain.com;"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is fine. The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-6.4) shows the `dmarc-sep`, which is defined as %x3b (';'), is optional for the trailing DMARC record segment.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't require a trailing semi-colon. I've inspected a lot of DMARC records and I never seen one with with trailing semi-colon. The trailing semi-colon might actually cause issues with validators.

Answer (score 2):

An errata clearly states a trailing semicolon needs to be present for the "DMARC1" version tag.

I was wondering why I got errors from some testing platforms, but not from others, with DMARC external domain authorization for rua and ruf, which usually contain only the "v=DMARC1" tag with nothing else. Apparently in this particular case the trailing semicolon is required, even if its the only and last one.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5440

Courtesy of internet.nl